# How to show options of an html select side by side using only css?

Tags: html, css

I need to have the options of an html select (with option "size" so to visualize it like a 5 lines textarea) showing side by side, like in this jfiddle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wmgo13L/4/)

I could achieve my goal using this css

```
select {
    width: 100%;
}
select#myselect option {
    width: 6%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    border-color: darkgray;
}
```

but it's working perfectly only on chrome. In firefox the option "float:left" seem not to work and the options are showed one under the other. In Safari the option "width:6%" is not working and the option element occupies 100% of the width of the select. Neither the border is working, but this is less important

It is possible to achieve the same chrome result in all browser?

**EDIT:** adding "display:inline" to the options show them side by side on firefox but all go on one single line, resulting in the last elements not to show at all, like in this jsfiddle

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wmgo13L/23/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline;` to the css.

Comment: Can't test on safari.

Comment: Should have been more specific. Did you add to `select#myselect option` css?

Comment: Yea, sorry, you're right. Thank you! It's working on firefox, but not working on safari, unfortunately

Comment: Maybe `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: nope, tried. The display etc solves the float left ignored problem. Safari ignores another thing: the width of the option element

Comment: Ive seen this in a few posts but not sure what it does: `-webkit-appearance: none;`.

Comment: no  fortune still AND the display inline put all option on one single line, look the  jsfiddle in the edit of the question

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't support the `inline` and `inline-block` nore the left floating for `<option>` and, i think, with good reasons: first, cause the `<select><option>` is not ment to work in that way and, secoundary, cause the `display:inline` is totally incompatible with the iphone rendering of the element itself;
cause this, also the possibility of controlling the `with` of the element is not supported.